# flutter how to display a subCollection for all the documents?

Tags: firebase, flutter, collections, stream, document

I have a collection of restaurants and a subcollection of orders for each restaurant. And, I was trying to make a list View  for the orders of all the restaurants. In the code below I was able to list only the orders of the first restaurant. Also I tried to do it using a stream builder but it does not work. I will be too happy if someone help me :)

```
  Future getOrders() async{
List list_of_restaureants = await Firestore.instance.collection("Restaurants")
    .getDocuments().then((val) => val.documents);
for (int i=0; i<list_of_restaureants.length; i++) {
  QuerySnapshot qn = await Firestore.instance.collection("Restaurants")
      .document(list_of_restaureants[i].documentID.toString()).collection("Orders").getDocuments();
  return qn.documents;
}}
```

---

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: getOrders(),
              builder: (_,snapshot){
                if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );}
                else{
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (_,index){
                      return  new ListTile(
                        title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data['phone']),
                        subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].data['Address']),
                      );
                    },);
                }
              },
            ),
```

[Database collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyxbM.png)

[Database subcollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl09u.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a really simple mistake. In the for loop you add to the list and then return it. Therefore as soon as the first document gets added, it returns the list without finising the for loop. So it gets for only one restaurant. Instead, do this

```
  Future getOrders() async{
List list_of_restaureants = await Firestore.instance.collection("Restaurants")
    .getDocuments().then((val) => val.documents);
List documentsToReturn;
for (int i=0; i<list_of_restaureants.length; i++) {
  QuerySnapshot qn = await Firestore.instance.collection("Restaurants") .document(list_of_restaureants[i].documentID.toString()).collection("Orders").getDocuments();
  documentsToReturn.addAll(qn.documents);   
    }
  return documentsToReturn;
}
```

Comment: it also gives me this error "The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)" . I think my whole code is wrong. Is there another method to do it?. And I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @YousefBagais Sorry for the late response. Could you please add print statements for both the lists and show the output because I want to see which list is empty and when

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem i think Siddharth Agrawal already gave you the right answere.

For your second question your error lies in this code snippet:

```
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data['phone']),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].data['Address']),
```

you would rather access the data like this:

```
 snapshot.data['phone']
 snapshot.data['Address']
```

Comment: my apologies but it gives me the same error. I think because as Siddharth Agrawal said the getOrders() function will return a list not a document. And, idk how to solve it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think he means that you get a list of documents. At which point does the code break? Did you try to set some breakpoints?

Comment: I had an error in my example could you try again please?

Comment: the code break at the future of the future builder because it calls a list. how I can display  this list of documents? what should be the future?